# How center whole page layout on paper stock with memoir

Tags: memoir

I'm using this `memoir` layout on the indicated stock size and with the indicated typeblock size.
How do I modify this, keeping the same stock size and typeblock size, but so as to *center the entire printed area* — headers, text area, footers, footnotes — on the physical stock?

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% PAGE LAYOUT
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{55.25pc}{38pc}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{44pc}{28pc}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}    
\makeheadrule {headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\mainheads}{%
\makeevenhead{headings}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark}{}%
}
\mainheads

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\section{The first section}
\lipsum[1-7]%
\footnote{Be sure to note this footnote!}
\lipsum[8-10]%
\footnote{\lipsum[20]}    
\lipsum[11-12]

\end{document}
```

Presumably I will add the `onesided` option to `memoir`, but which dimensions do I have to change how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want this?

[[image: centred page[1]]

This centres the page on the paper i.e. the text block, headers, footers, margins and all the rest of it.

```
\documentclass[showtrims,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% PAGE LAYOUT
\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\setpagecc{55.25pc}{38pc}{*}
\settypeblocksize{44pc}{28pc}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\copypagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{chapter}{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}    
\makeheadrule {headings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\mainheads}{%
\makeevenhead{headings}{\bfseries\sffamily\thepage}{\bfseries\sffamily\rightmark}{}%
}
\mainheads

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\section{The first section}
\lipsum[1-7]%
\footnote{Be sure to note this footnote!}
\lipsum[8-10]%
\footnote{\lipsum[20]}    
\lipsum[11-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain the calculations you did to arrive at this?

Comment: @murray I just read the manual and used `\setpagecc` which centres the printed area on the stock. No calculations required.